# How to add Zend Guard Run-time in wamp

Tags: php, windows, wamp, zend-guard

Zend Guard Run-time support missing!

> One or more files on this web site were encoded by ZendGuard and the required run-time support is not installed or properly configured.

When I try to run some script encrypted with zend gurad I am getting this error.
Please help me to resolve this.

i have encrypted my php code using zend guard , also i downloaded and  added zend guard dll, changed the php.ini as follows

```
zend_loader.enable=1
zend_loader.disable_licensing=0
zend_extension="c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/ZendLoader.dll"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Thread safety must be disabled (look at `phpinfo()`).

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things that you can check to see if the Loader is even active. Type php -v on the console and you should get something like this

```
[root@centos ~]# php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jan 11 2012 19:53:01)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies with 
Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
```

If you don't see the Zend Guard Loader then you have an initial problem loading the module. It will also tell you if you have other problems like the wrong version.

Check out my doc about [Zend Loader problems](http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/Web-Hosting/Zend-Guard/Run-time-support-missing) as well.